# How to clear a selected value in Selectize.js dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I have a [*selectize.js*](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) dropdown and I have to clear the selected value .

I have tried this (as suggested in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497833/how-do-i-set-the-selectize-js-option-list-programmatically)):

```
var selectize = $("#optionNetFlow")[0].selectize;
selectize.clear();
```

But it gives the following error:

> [image]

When I change it to this:

```
var selectize = $("#optionNetFlow").selectize;
selectize.clear();
```

I gives this error:

> [image]

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: If you check [docs](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#methods_other) mentioned in [provided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497833/how-do-i-set-the-selectize-js-option-list-programmatically) **incorrect** answer (just imagine - 9 vote ups for incorrect answer. Well, maybe other part of answer is correct, but the first code line is deadly wrong) - you will see how it has to be done.

Comment: Thanks @Regent, I got it sorted. Thanks for help.

Comment: It happens sometimes. Sometimes without any adequate reason. Just relax. It's not that you have low reputation, you know. My vote up can compensate 2.5 downvotes.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I finally found the answer here [**Selectize.js Demos**](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/)

What works for me is:

```
 var $select = $('#optionNetFlow').selectize();
 var control = $select[0].selectize;
 control.clear();
```

what I was missing `var $select = $('#optionNetFlow').selectize();` before applying the solution provided in above question's answer.

Now I am to get all the functions in console like :

[image]

Comment: This solution also removes the record(clear the dropdown list). You can no longer search in the list.

Comment: @khan No it doesn't. Just checked this solution - it works perfectly. I can still search and select the cleared item. Version used to check this - **Selectize.js v0.12.4**.

Answer (score 29):

Try this,

```
$("#optionNetFlow")[0].selectize.clear();
```

Comment: This is the best way, you don't have to store the selectize in a global variable when initializing, just call this whenever you need.

Comment: Best answer. And after you have cleared the input, you might need to focus it, to open list. Use for that: focus().

Comment: that's great it works for me I just added the ID of my select box and boom it worked thanks a lot

Answer (score 11):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/2gnq1ruv/204/

**JS:-**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $select = $('#input-tags').selectize({
        persist: false,
        create: true
    });

    $("#btnClear").on("click", function () {
        var selectize = $select[0].selectize;
        selectize.clear();

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I got sorted it out. +1 for jsfiddle.

Comment: what does persist do ?

Comment: @astroanu - It says "keep option after it's been un-selected or not?" as a boolean flag, basically. Source is Usage docs:  https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md

Answer (score 9):

All other answers either clear a single selectize or need a specific reference to the selectize in the moment of it's creation.

The solution below, on the other hand, works for any number of selectize elements you have inside any form; you just need to specify the desired form:

```
$('form').find('.selectized').each(function(index, element) { element.selectize && element.selectize.clear() })
```

The rationale is that Selectize keeps the original  element in the DOM (hiding it), adds a reference to the selectize on the `.selectize` property of the DOM element and adds a CSS class `selectized` to it.

So the solution finds all the elements that have the CSS class `selectized`, loops through them and calls `element.selectize.clear()`.

Comment: +1 for this! But just a question, what does this line means? 
`element.selectize && element.selectize.clear()`

Comment: It means: if element.selectize isn't null or undefined, then clear it

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', 'div.selectize-input div.item', function(e) {
    var select = $('#services').selectize();
    var selectSizeControl = select[0].selectize;
    // 1. Get the value
    var selectedValue = $(this).attr("data-value");
    // 2. Remove the option
    select[0].selectize.removeItem(selectedValue);
    // 3. Refresh the select
    select[0].selectize.refreshItems();
    select[0].selectize.refreshOptions();
});
```

This do not remove the item from the select, just remove it from the selected options.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you have multi select, and do want to restore selected items in the drop-down list (hide selected set to true).

```
var selectize = $("#select-item").selectize;
//clone array
var items = selectize.items.slice(0);
for (var i in items) {
    selectize.removeItem(items[i]);
}
selectize.refreshOptions();
```